# How supply range to normal mode key-binding?

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode, line-numbers, range

I've created a mapping to a function that accepts a range. Like this:

```
command! -range Test call TestFunc(<range>,<line1>,<line2>)
nnoremap <leader>t :Test<CR>
```

How do I supply a specific range to the mapped command, in normal mode?

For example: from current line to line 81, apply mapped command `t`. Something like `.,81\t`.

How can the same thing be done using marks?

The function, by the way, is written thus:

```
function! TestFunc(r,l1,l2) abort
    if a:r == 0
        echo "No range"
    elseif a:r == 1
        echo "Single Line given (like :22Test)"
    else
        echo "Line range given (like :1,23Test, '<,'>Test or %Test)"
    endif
endfunction
```

It simply says what sort of range it got. (I don't remember what the abort statement was in aid of).

When I have actually applied this to functions, I've required it to work both with and without ranges.

Comment: I would probably adjust the mapping to be `:nnoremap <leader>t :Test<C-b>`; then you can type the range and press enter.

Comment: How would you type the range - you mean in command mode? Typing a range with a comma in command mode seems not to work.

Comment: Yes, _e.g._, `\t.,81<cr>`, since `<C-b>` puts your cursor between `:` and `Test`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the cursor is on line #80 and `<leader>` defaults to backslash, type directly <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>.

The point is that typing `N:` in Normal mode, where `N` is arbitrary number, is converted by Vim to `:.,.+N-1`. So you have to supply number of lines in range (rather than last line number).

Comment: Yes, this is nice. I do that already. Problem is when you want to apply the command to a range of lines that goes off the screen. Like from 133 to 1781, for example. If I'm on line 133, surely there's a command mode way of saying, 'here's a line number - run the command on all lines between here and there?

Comment: @marking Well, you can modify your mapping to pass `v:count` as last line number instead. But you hardly want to have two mappings for the same operation. So it's more custom to do this in Visual like `V1781gg\t` and leave `v:count` for line range as it normally is.

Answer (score 2):

There are typically two ways to pass a range to a Normal-mode command.

One is to use a Visual selection (which is not exactly a Normal-mode command, but a Visual-mode one, but still pretty close) and the other is to create a mapping that takes an operator and acts on the range resulting of the operator or motions that follows it.

For the Visual-mode command, you get the `'<` and `'>` marks set to the beginning and end of the Visual selection, so you can simply call your user command with:

```
:'<,'>Test
```

But since Vim will add the range automatically when you press `:` from Visual mode (which already shows up with `:'<,'>`), you don't even need to add that into your mapping! All you need is:

```
xnoremap <leader>t :Test<CR>
```

To use this mapping on range from current line to line 81, you can use:

```
V81G\t
```

That's assuming backslash as your `<leader>` key. `V` will start Visual mode, `81G` move to line 81, extending the selection and finally `\t` invoke the Visual-mode mapping.

For the second option, creating a mapping that expects an operator, you set the `'operatorfunc'` option to a function that will act on the range, then issue the `g@` command, which waits for an operator and invokes the function with the `'[` and `']` marks set.

In your case:

```
function! TestOpfunc(type)
    '[,']Test
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <leader>t :set operatorfunc=TestOpfunc<CR>g@
```

You can then invoke it with:

```
\t81G
```

Where `81G` is the motion taken as the operator to define the range where to act, in this case from the current line until line 81.

See `:help :map-operator` or `:help g@` for more details and examples on how to use `g@` and define an operator function. The examples also show how to reuse the function for the counterpart Visual-mode mapping.

Comment: I've been avoiding visual mode. But what you propose --- V81G\t --- would be ideal if I could get it to work! The other thing looks pretty groovy. But I shall have to find time to rewrite the function(s) where I'm actually doing this? One proviso is that the target functions must work also if they are not given a range.

Comment: When I do V81G\t, nothing happens! - it just swallows the \t and remains in --Visual Mode--, waiting....

Comment: That's odd about the mapping not working... If you use `V81G` for the Visual selection, then `:` (will show up with the range, as in the answer), then you run `Test` command in that range, will it work? About the Operator-Pending one. No, you won't need to rewrite anything, the example I gave above should work directly with your user-command, assuming it can take ranges just fine... You *can* refactor it to have a single function that does it all (depending on it's arguments), but you don't need to...

Answer (score 2):

My preferred method here is to just let you enter the range from the place you normally do: on the Ex command line:

```
nnoremap <leader>t :Test<C-b>
```

Since `<C-b>` puts your cursor between at the beginning of the line, you can type `\t.,81<CR>`.

Comment: Appending `.,` to the end of mapping might save two keystrokes... Or sometimes result in typing two extra backspaces, of course.